# Measure of a set satisfying $ x \in B$ if and only if $x + k/2^n \in B $

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Say we have a probability space $(\Omega, M, P) = ([0,1], \text{ Borel Sets}, \text{ Lebesgue measure})$. Suppose we have the following set $B \in M$ such that
$x \in B$ if and only if $x + k/2^n \in B$
for any $n \geq 1$ and $0 \leq k \leq 2^n$. (Here addition is modulo $1$.)

Does it then follow that $P(B)$ can only equal $0$ or $1$
by any chance?

Comment: Not sure if this is true: if $P(B) = \epsilon > 0$, then $B$ contains an open interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f\in L^2$ define $f_n(x):={1\over 2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}f\left(x+{k\over 2^n}\right)$. By calculating Fourier coefficients, we see that $f_n$ converges in $L^2$ to the constant function $\int f$. Let $f(x)=1_B(x)$ for a set $B$ with the property in your question. Then $f_n(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$, so by the convergence result $f(x)=\int f$ almost everywhere. If $1_B(x)$ is a constant almost everywhere, then the constant must be either 0 or 1, and this gives the result.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution! When I compute the Fourier coefficients of $f_n$, I am actually getting that each $f_n$ is in fact $f_n = \int f$... Is this what you mean? Thanks

Comment: @TomMosher Yes, that's right.